# How to exclude a row from sorting in datatable with R Markdown HTML output

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I have a datatable within an R Markdown document that I am rendering to HTML. The table has ordering enabled, allowing the user to re-order fields by clicking on them. What I would like to do is exclude a specific row from ordering, so that it will always stay in the same position (the last row) regardless of the ordering by the user.

For example, in this table, I would like to keep the `Hornet Sportabout` as the last row, regardless of how the user orders the columns:

````
---
title: "Test Datatable"
date: "August 14, 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

mtcars[1:5, 1:2] %>%
  datatable(options = list(ordering = TRUE))
```
````

[image]

Desired result when user has ordered by mpg for example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate answer using dplyr (which is a little more compact)

```
# Create sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  Vehicle = c('Mazda RX4','Mazda RX4 Wag','Datsun 710','Hornet 4 Drive','Hornet Sportabout'),
  mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7),
  cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8)
)

# Create new variable to identify rows you want to keep at the bottom.
df$keepatbottom <- 0;
df$keepatbottom[df$Vehicle=='Hornet Sportabout'] <- 1;

# Sort by mpg and keepatbottom at the same time
library(dplyr)
df <- arrange(df,keepatbottom,mpg)
```

Comment: This answer works well for my purpose.  Could it be adapted to allow filtering?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to identify the rows you want at the bottom in some way.  Essentially you'll need to sort by two columns.  This sample code works:

```
# Create sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  Vehicle = c('Mazda RX4','Mazda RX4 Wag','Datsun 710','Hornet 4 Drive','Hornet Sportabout'),
  mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7),
  cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8)
)

# Sort lowest to highest by mpg
df <- df[order(df$mpg, decreasing=FALSE), ]

# Create new variable to identify rows you want to keep at the bottom.
df$keepatbottom <- 0;
df$keepatbottom[df$Vehicle=='Hornet Sportabout'] <- 1;
df <- df[order(df$keepatbottom, decreasing=FALSE), ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not trying to order the table with R, rather I'm trying to ensure that in a datatable in the html_document produced from this code, the order of a certain row cannot be changed by the user. I've updated my question to be more explicit on what I'm looking for.